# Sorting by length in Jinja

Tags: python, sorting, jinja2

I have table `users` that contain column `username` and `entries` (a one-to-many relationship with table `entries`). In my HTML file, I want to display the username and the number of entries from the particular user.

It looks like this:

```
{% for i in users %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ i.username }}</td>
    <td>{{ i.entries|length }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to sort the rows from the user who has the biggest number of entries to the least.

I try this but it doesn't work:

```
{% for i in users|sort(entries|length) %}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: maybe you should sort it in SQL query or in `view` before you send it to display.

Comment: IS the problem solved?

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 Not yet. Not sure how to prepare PostgreSQL query in `view`. I posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62840030/how-do-i-prepare-query-in-view-before-passing-it-to-jinja

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally create your `query-set` in you `view` and in your template, you can access it like so

```
{% for user in users|sort(attribute="length")
<tr>
    <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.entries|length }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Using `length` attribute on your item, you can do so with `sort(attribute='length')`. Taken from the [Jinja2 sort filter documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#sort)